# How can I clear the data of BufferAttibute in GPU with threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I set an BufferAttribute of BufferGeometry in threejs, it likes this:

```
 geometry.setAttribute("xxx", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(array), 3))
```

and how can I delete it without effectting other attributes?

when I use

```
geometry.deleteAttribute("xxx")
```

and set the value of needUpdate as true , the memory of GPU seems unchanged, data still exist!!!

I am trying to dynamically set attibutes of geometry in threeJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to dispose individual attributes. You have to call `dispose()` on the geometry object and then create a new one with your updated set of buffer attributes.